NextJS: Why NextResponse.redirect is not triggering on production
I want to implement a simple login flow. I have a login form that takes the user's phone and password. The credentials are sent to the API after submitting the form by calling the login function (mutation function returned by the Tanstack Query useMutation hook). Inside the onSuccess callback of the mutation function, I set the token value returned by the API as a cookie using the setCookie function of the cookies-next package (version: 4.2.1), and also redirect the user to the /projects route using useRouter() from next/navigation:
const { login, isLoggingIn } = useLogin();
const router = useRouter()
    
const onSubmit = ({ phone, password }) => {
    login(
        { phone, password },
        {
            onSuccess: ({ data: { token } }) => {
                setCookie("token", token);
                router.push('/projects')
            },
        }
    );
};

For protecting my routes, I use middleware:
import { getCookie } from "cookies-next";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
    matcher: "/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|assets|favicon.ico|verify-email).*)",
};

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const res = NextResponse.next();
    const token = getCookie("token", { req, res });
    const isAuthRoute = req.nextUrl.pathname === "/auth";

    if (!token && !isAuthRoute) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", req.url));
    }

    if (token && isAuthRoute) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/projects", req.url));
    }

    return res;
}


The code works perfectly without any issues on development (http://localhost:3000/). The user fills out the form, the form gets submitted and form data is sent to the API. The API responds back with the token. The token gets set in the browser's cookies and user gets redirected successfully. The issue occurs when I push the code to production and also when I run npm run build and then npm run start on my local machine. After submitting the form, the token is provided by the backend and is set successfully as cookie (Checked the browser cookies). But the part where the user must get redirected is not working.
Then if you wait for about 30 seconds and submit the form again, the page gets redirected successfully this time!
Also, if you Refresh the page after the first submit, since the token is set to cookies, the page gets redirected to /projects by the middleware.
These are what I've tried so far to solve the issues:

Using a private browser tab (Incognito) (I was suspecting something is cached!)
Using NextResponse.rewrite() instead of NextResponse.redirect()
Running router.refresh() before running router.push()
Setting status to 303: NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", req.url), { status: 303 })

I must mention that I use:

Next.Js version 14.2.5 (App directory)
cookies-next version 4.2.1

Note: My .env files content are identical for both development and production.
Edit: I removed the whole middleware.ts and everything works fine, and user gets redirected to /projects! Therefore, it look like the problem lies in the middleware.
I appreciate any help anyone could kindly provide.

This sounds rather weird. Normally such kind of errors after build occur when Next.js builds a page/endpoint statically which isn't supposed to be static, or if you have different NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variables in dev and in prod. Are you sure onSuccess got invoked (maybe you can log something to check). For from what I understand the whole middleware.ts part is not really part of the problem/question, right?

@NotX I am pretty sure onSuccess gets invoked, because I checked the browser's cookies, and the token provided by API is set successfully. Also, I think the problem lies in middleware.ts because I removed the whole middleware.ts and everything works fine, and user gets redirected to /projects!

Not sure why but based on this comment, using the whole website url somehow fixed the problem. Here is how I modified my code:
// middleware.ts
if (token && isAuthRoute) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("htttps://mysite.com/projects", req.url));
}


I write my middle-ware in a different way. According to your problem you are redirecting from the middleware as well as pushing to the router. Please try by replacing the if blocks by this.
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const res = NextResponse.next();
    const token = getCookie("token", { req, res });
    const isAuthRoute = req.nextUrl.pathname === "/auth";

    if (!token && !isAuthRoute) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/auth", req.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}


And I would recommend to check the token from here also if the token is valid or not. Below is how I write the middleware.
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { jwtVerify } from 'jose'; // requires installing

export async function middleware(req) {
    const token = req.cookies.get('token');
    console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url));
    }
    try {
        const { payload } = await jwtVerify(token, new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.JWT_SECRET));
        return NextResponse.next();
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.url));
    }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/'], // paste your matcher here
};


If I remove the second if statement (if (token && isAuthRoute)), I won't be able to redirect the users to the root route (/projects) when they try to navigate to /auth while having a token. I mean, the app must redirect the users from /auth to /projects if the user has a token.

By the way, I check for token validation by sending a request to the API in a separate if statement. I didn't mention it in my question for the sake of simplicity: if (token && !isAuthRoute) { return await handleTokenValidation(token, req, res) }

As you are pushing to '''/projects''' after login the '''next()''' function will redirect there without any problem. As I have seen in your code that you used '''router.push("/projects")'''

Not sure if I'm following you correctly. But first of all: I cannot remove the second if-statement (if (token && isAuthRoute)) because if users try to directly reach /auth while having a token, they must get redirected to /projects. Secondly, I cannot remove router.push(/projects)  either, because the middleware won't get invoked after the login function is executed, therefore, no route change happens.
